# How to force display of tooltip in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

Is it possible force to display of tooltip in a control?  I have no idea how do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 ToolTip mytoolTip = new ToolTip();
 mytoolTip.ShowAlways = true; // to force it
 mytoolTip.Show("This is my ToolTip", myControl);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.Show("Hello", myControl);
```

See [MSDN ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx)